# Installing djatoka on tomcat 6 on RHEL 6.3

Tags: tomcat6, rhel6

Can someone help me get djatoka image viewer running on my RHEL 6.3 machine (an EC2 instance hosted by Amazon Web Services)?

Tomcat 6 installed nicely (using `sudo yum install tomcat6 tomcat6-webapps tomcat6-admin-webapps`) as I can see the "Congratulations you've installed Tomcat" page.

I think I've largely installed djatoka (by downloading the tar, untarring and dumping the .war file in tomcat's wepabbs directory) as I can see its test page when I append the name of the file in tomcat's webapp directory to the url. However, the test page itself doesn't work, and doesn't output any errors.

The official installation instructions only refer to tomcat5 and use a script called `catalina.sh` which doesn't appear to be present on tomcat6. The community mailing lists on haven't had any responses from informed users since 2010.

Does anyone here know anything about djatoka, or how I might go about working out what's broken with the config, in the absence of community support?

I'm at my wits end, so I may have missed some detail, please leave a comment if there's any extra info I should include.

Comment: Might want to try with StackOverflow or SuperUser SE groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by editing the source, so that it didn't rely on the value of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable (which was automatically unset due to Tomcat being a "setuid" program), then compiled with ant.

It was also essential to use the Sun/Oracle JDK as djatoka uses some of the sun classes (which is bad practise, as it commits the server build to a specific distribution, and version, of Java!)

Also had to change a line in tomcat.sh (the djatoka startup script) to remove a reference to "catalina.sh" (the old tomcat startup script) and replace it with "service tomcat6".

Answer (score 0):

You can try to deploy with built in manager `http://localhost:8080/manager/html`

Comment: I've made some progress, it seems that the webapp was successfully deployed, just the init script was failing under SELinux. Namely (as far as I can tell) the exported value for LD_LIBRARY_PATH was being lost as root was launching the service, but it was running as tomcat.